I am trying to do a board outline with "-" and "+" but I am getting unexpected output
I mentioned the condition to print at particular places but instead of printing at those locations code just appends "+" to "-" even with range condition it exceeds the limit.
I wanted to print "+" at 0, 8, 16, 24 index locations and print "-" in between them.
def display(board):
    for row in range(25):
        print("-", end = "")
        if row == 0 or row == 8 or row == 16 or row == 24:
            print("+", end = "")

The outcome when I invoke the function is:
-+--------+--------+--------+

I tried to modify code so that "+" stays in condition loop when "-" is outside but output is different
def display(board):
    for row in range(25):
        if row == 0 or row == 8 or row == 16 or row == 24: 
            print("+", end = "")
        print("-", end = "")

+--------+--------+--------+-

My expected outcome is supposed to be:
+-------+-------+-------+


Since the outcome is fixed, why not print('+-------+-------+-------+', end='')?  Do you want a newline at the end of the print?  then remove , end=''.  You don't get a newline with the current code.

it's not fixed it's just starting line of a board. I am trying to create a board with those two symbols

The code shown gives the same output each time.  That's fixed.  You're just missing an else: to print correctly.  If you want help with the variable board to print the whole thing, you should show what the value of board is and the final result.

You've just got to use an if else to only print 1 char per iteration of your loop. Without the else, you are printing twice on each multiple of 8.
def display(board):
    for row in range(25):
        if row == 0 or row == 8 or row == 16 or row == 24:
            print("+", end = "")
        else
            print("-", end = "")

You could also simplify the code and make it a bit more readable using some math.
def display(board):
    for row in range(25):
        if row % 8 == 0:
            print("+", end = "")
        else
            print("-", end = "")

